# Calculate determinant of unitary matrices based on SVD implementation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, svd

I have a real square matrix `X` which I need to perform a Singular Value Decomposition on. Now, performing the operation

`X=USV^T`

as U and V are orthogonal, we know that `det(X)=±det(S)` and `det(S)` is non-negative as singular values are non-negative.

Now, I need to know the sign of the determinants of `U` and `V` (which is the same as knowing the determinants, of course). However, the naive approach costs me `2 O(N^3)`

I was wondering whether someone knows of a way to either

1. Infer the sign of the determinants of `U` and `V` as a bi-product of the SVD-implementation in `numpy`,`scipy` or a similar library in Python, without having to call `det(U)` and `det(V)`.
2. Calculate the determinant of an orthogonal matrix which is faster than the default implementation of `det(U)`, based on the fact that `U/V` is orthogonal.

Comment: Interesting question. I think you have better chances of getting an answer at [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Now also posted at [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40345/20688) which is good!

Comment: Are you implementing SVD by yourself, if not, your question reduces to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900553